# ng-virtual-repeat and $last

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am currently working on a project based on Angular Material. When we use "ng-repeat", there is "$last" for us to check the final object. Is there anything similar to "$last" for the directive "ng-virtual-repeat"? I have searched using Google for answers but it seems that there are no articles related to that. Or is there any other way to achieve the same functionality as "$last" do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it expose an `$index` like `ng-repeat` ? If so, you can just check on `if ($index === myList.length - 1)`